# Apache Openssl Compression

Tags: apache, security, ssl, openssl

I am using openssl 1.0.1 on os x el capitan. I want to enable TLS compression. I have set `SSLCompression on` but still doesn't do compression.

P.S. I know that compression is unsafe but I have to enable it to demonstrate CRIME attack for my class. I have also got browser that supports compression, so browser doesn't seem to be issue. The ServerHello message always decide to use `null(0)` compression.

Answer (score 0):

Then the issue seems to be located serverside.

If you are the administrator of the server and if the server runs a recent OS, I'm afraid you'll probably have to manually compile OpenSSL with option `zlib` on it.

Comment: I did recompile with zlib option. Still doesn't make a difference. Any other way?

Comment: Is the server accessible from the internet? If yes, you can try to test it using https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/ and see if the report says that Compression is enabled. If not, you can simply try to connect to your server with a version of OpenSSL that supports compression, by using `openssl s_client -connect myserver:443` and look for the `Compression` field in the output.

Comment: It says Compression:none. I don't know what else should I do. Do I need to put SSLCompression on in httpd.conf?

Comment: I don't think so, I think you have to specify to Apache where is the custom OpenSSL version you compiled: https://blog.ivanristic.com/2013/08/compiling-apache-with-static-openssl.html